# Can we change price for In app Billing product play store

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I have integrated In app billing in my app. But I couldn't find If I can change price for a product or not after publishing my app ?

I found that we can not change price for `subscription` product. But couldn't find anything for `Managed` product.

Can I change product price after publishing an app or not ? If yes then How long it will take to affect throughout the Play store.

If there is google document related to this and you post a link then it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

From the Google Play Console:

> Please note that you can NOT change the price and billing period for your subscription after it was activated

Comment: True, but Google also says this: "To change the price of a subscription, you can publish a new subscription product ID at a new price, then offer it in your app instead of the original product. Users who have already purchased will continue to be charged at the original price, but new users will be charged at the new price."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change prices of managed products.
Just update the price in the Developer Console and Save. It might take an hour or so to propagate around all the servers but it is usually quick.

Comment: If you can post a link of a  official document where it says this then it would be great.

Comment: Note that it is confusing. You can change de price in the developer console but if you do not click on "Auto-convert prices now" it will be not reflected in the app. You HAVE TO click on that button and then save, otherwise the price that is shown in the list in the developer console is NOT the same that the price in your app. For more read this http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-catalog

Comment: Dont forget to check the box "Overwrite existing prices" too.