# Overwrite country price for an existing in-app product in Google play

Tags: android, in-app-billing

We have an existing in-app product defined for our Android application on Google play.

I want to overwrite its price for some countries,but the following message is shown in the in-app product's page in Play's developer console:

"Please note that you can NOT change the price and billing period for your subscription after it was activated."

What can I do to change the price? Do I have to create a new in-app product? Isn't there an easy way to change the price whenever I want from the developer console for already activated products?

Comment: Maybe you should give a look at [this Thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131695/can-we-change-price-for-in-app-billing-product-play-store

Comment: It states the same I included in my question "Please note...activated". I want the solution . i.e. create new In-app subscription product. But how will this affect existing users?